# Android setText erases past data

Tags: android, textview, settext

Sorry, if this question seems too easy, but i'm new, and i'm still learning!

What i want to do, is to setText to a textview. I want to print the first 5 strings of an arraylist. Therefore i have done the following:

```
           for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String date_time = allDate_time.get( i );
            String date = date_time.substring( 0, date_time.indexOf( "T" ) );
            String time = date_time.substring( date_time.indexOf( "T" ) + 1, date_time.indexOf( "+" ) );
            textView2.setText( allId.get( i ) + "  " + allTemp.get( i ) + "  " + allHum.get( i ) + "  " + allBat.get( i ) + "  " + allMode.get( i ) + "  " + date + "  " + time + "  " + allLux.get( i ) + "\n" );
        }
```

Unfortunately, i suspect the setText to erase the past data, and only to print the last possibility. Is there anything i can do, so setText doesn't erase past data?

*EDIT*

```
textView2.append();
```

this worked for me. Thanks a lot for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Use Append method for instead setText method

Answer (score 1):

define a StringBuilder before the loop and append your text to the builder and the after the loop add the value to textview.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder =  new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        String date_time = allDate_time.get( i );
        String date = date_time.substring( 0, date_time.indexOf( "T" ) );
        String time = date_time.substring( date_time.indexOf( "T" ) + 1, date_time.indexOf( "+" ) );
        stringBuilder.append(allId.get( i ) + "  " + allTemp.get( i ) + "  " + allHum.get( i ) + "  " + allBat.get( i ) + "  " + allMode.get( i ) + "  " + date + "  " + time + "  " + allLux.get( i ) + "\n" )
    }
    textview.settext(stringBuilder.toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Set can text like this

```
textview.setText(textview.getText().toString + "Your new text here");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this easy way

```
 textView2.setText("");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    String date_time = allDate_time.get( i );
                    String date = date_time.substring( 0, date_time.indexOf( "T" ) );
                    String time = date_time.substring( date_time.indexOf( "T" ) + 1, date_time.indexOf( "+" ) );

                    String toText = textView2.getText().toString()+allId.get( i );

                    textView2.setText(toText );
                }
```

Hope it works.